# Quando usar list comprehension e não filter+lambda?

Tags: python, expressões-lambda

Boa noite, pessoal.
Estudando aqui, achei fantásticas as funções de *List Comprehension* e *filter+lambda*, mas ambas me pareceram bem similares em alguns pontos...

Quando é que devo usar *List Comprehension* em vez de *filter+lambda*, e vice-versa ?

Answer (score 5):

Eu não diria que uma é "melhor" ou "pior" que a outra, na realidade tanto em desempenho quanto em concisão as duas formas são bastante semelhantes. A única coisa que muda é o **estilo** de programação.

Estilo imperativo (*loop*):

```
impares = []
for i in range(1000):
    if i % 2:
        impares.append(i)
```

Estilo funcional (`filter`):

```
impares = filter(lambda i: i % 2, range(1000))       # Python 2
impares = list(filter(lambda i: i % 2, range(1000))) # Python 3
```

Estilo declarativo (compreensão de lista):

```
impares = [i for i in range(1000) if i % 2]
```

Todas as três formas são legíveis e devem possuir desempenho semelhante. O estilo imperativo é menos conciso, de modo que eu só usaria quando a expressão de teste fosse mais complexa (o que faria um único lambda se tornar demasiadamente extenso, exigindo uma função auxiliar pra se manter legível).

Pessoalmente, eu considero a compreensão de listas mais "leve pros olhos", de modo que eu nunca escrevo código usando `filter` (principalmente `filter` + `lambda`).

Quanto às questões de eficiência [apontadas por sergiopereira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92688/215), de fato o `filter` e as compreensões de lista criam uma nova lista, às vezes sem necessidade, o que aumenta o consumo de memória. Já o `ifilter`, as expressões geradoras e os *generators* não criam nem computam nada antes que seja a hora de usar os resultados de fato (e não criam listas persistentes na memória).

Estilo imperativo (*generator*):

```
def impar(elems):
    for i in elems:
        if i % 2:
            yield i

for x in impar(range(1000)):
    ...
```

Estilo funcional (`ifilter`):

```
for x in ifilter(lambda i: i % 2, range(1000)):   # Python 2
    ...
for x in filter(lambda i: i % 2, range(1000)):    # Python 3
    ...
```

Estilo declarativo (expressão geradora):

```
for x in (i for i in range(1000) if i % 2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

A resposta depende um pouco da versão do Python que você está usando. Em Python3 o `filter` foi refeito utilizando `itertools.ifilter` do Python 2.x.

A grande vantagem do `ifilter` é o uso menor de memória pois a lista é produzida à medida que vai sendo iterada.

```
# exemplo em Python 2.7
from itertools import ifilter
# lista de cem mil numeros (seria melhor ainda com xrange)
numbers = range(100000)

[n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]
# ==>  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ... 99998]
filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, numbers)
# ==>  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ... 99998]

# usando ifilter (ou filter em Python 3)
ifilter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, numbers)
# ==>  <itertools.ifilter object at 0x10d06ce10>
# A lista não foi criada, para ler os elementos é preciso iterar
for n in ifilter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, numbers):
    print n
# ==>  0
# ==>  2
# ==>  4
# ==>  ...
# ==>  99998
```

Fora os aspectos de eficiência no uso de memória e estética, eu não lembro de nada mais que diferencie as duas alternativas.

Comment: +1, mas cabe mencionar que existe um equivalente às compreensões de lista que possui a mesma eficiência do `ifilter` - as expressões geradoras.

Comment: Bem lembrado @mgibsonbr. Eu sempre lembro das **funções** geradoras mas nem percebo quando estou usando **expressões** geradoras.