# Para que serve o Yield?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yield

Há já algum tempo que tenho escrito alguns *scripts* básicos com o Python, em alguns tutoriais às vezes é-me apresentado o `yield`, que normalmente surge em estruturas de repetição comumente `while`. Para que serve? E como usar?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

O Python tem especificidades próprias mas essencialmente em todas linguagens funcionam igual. Ele cria um *generator*, ou seja, cria uma lista de dados que vão sendo consumidos sob demanda. Em geral é usado para dar melhores abstrações ao código. Tudo que se faz com ele, dá para fazer sem ele de forma muito semelhante, mas expondo o mecanismo de geração dos dados.

Ele retorna um valor mantendo o estado de onde parou. Quando executa de novo ele continua de onde parou. Ele controla o estado de um enumerador entre execuções da função.

```
def impar(elems):
    for i in elems:
        if i % 2:
            yield i

for x in impar(range(1000)):
```

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92690/101).

Este código imprimirá todos os ímpares de 0 à 1000. Ele vai chamar o método 500 vezes, cada vez trará um número ímpar. O compilador/biblioteca montará a estruturá interna para saber em que número ele está em cada chamada.

Claro que tem uma variável escondida que sobrevive além do ambiente interno da função. Então esse `i` não começa de novo em cada chamada da função. Note que você pode chamar a função `impar()` sem saber como ela faz a seleção internamente.

Este exemplo é simples e óbvio, mas pense em coisas mais complexas. Você abstrai melhor. Você diz que vai chamar um método que filtra os ímpares para você. Não interessa como. O que você vai fazer com a informação gerada é problema seu. A função com o `yield` tem responsabilidade única de gerar a informação.

Outro exemplo:

```
def numeros():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

print numeros()
print numeros()
print numeros()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Yield2.py).

Isto imprimirá 1, 2 e 3.

Veja [explicações em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101) e [PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50208/101).

Comment: Em poucas palavras, o `yield` _"come"_ alguns dos valores contidos numa estrutura de repetição, sem causar interrupções, é isto ?

Comment: É ao contrário. A ideia do come, é boa, vai pegando uma semente cada vez. Mas é com interrupções. O `yield` é um `return`, ele encerra a execução, ele interrompe. Mas o saco de sementes continua lá do jeito que você deixou. Não começa um saco novo toda vez que chamar, como ocorreria no `return`. Não precisa ser uma estrutura de repetição, mas precisa ter uma sequência de dados.

Comment: No caso, interrupções controladas ?

Comment: Sim, totalmente. Editei para dar um exemplo diferente.

Comment: Deu para entender, obrigado pelo tempo.

Comment: Por ser um exemplo didático seria mais interessante simplificar ao máximo a sintaxe. Ao passar o construtor para o for ao invés de impar(range(1000)) usar impar(1000), ou seja, o "range" vai para dentro do def, o que confunde menos.

Comment: Vale a pena ver esse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOMtQ4ocMGI&ab_channel=CoreySchafer) pra complementar ainda mais a resposta

Answer (score 9):

Complementando a resposta de Maniero, algumas características do ***yield***:

***Yield*** no Python é usado sempre que você precisa definir uma função de gerador de algo.
Você não pode usar ***yield*** fora de um generator function.

Quando você usa a instrução ***yield*** dentro de uma função, ela se transforma em uma função geradora.

Função geradora é uma função que retorna mais do que um valor - retorna uma série de valores.

Um uso comum é dentro de loops, como por exemplo:

```py
for value in simpleGeneratorFun():  
     print(value)
```

E a declaração da nossa função geradora seria algo assim:

```py
def simpleGeneratorFun():
    for i in range (1, 4):
        yield i
```

Sempre que a instrução ***yield*** ocorre dentro da função  geradora, o programa pausa a execução e retorna o valor para o chamador. No exemplo acima, ela retorna um `value` no `for`.

O ***yield*** retém o estado da função onde ela é pausada (ao retornar o `value`).

Da próxima vez, quando um chamador chamar a função geradora - no nosso caso, o `for` - o corpo da função executará a instrução de onde ela foi pausada, em vez de executar a primeira instrução.

Você pode chamar a função geradora, contanto que não tenha atingido sua última declaração, ou seja, na primeira vez que chamar `simpleGeneratorFun()` ela vai retornar 1. Na segunda, irá retornar 2, até chegar em 4.

Resumido, um pouco editado para melhor entendimento e traduzido de:
https://www.csestack.org/python-yield-vs-return-explained-detail-examples/

Answer (score -1):

o yield faz parte do protocolo de iteradores do python, ele evita vc ter que criar o elemento iterável efetivamente, tornando seu código mais escalável, poupando memória principalmente.
Como exemplo, imagine que vc tem uma lista de números inteiros e queira um loop não por esses números e sim pelo quadrado deles. Uma solução natural seria criar uma lista iterando por cada elemento da primeira e alocando em cada posição o quadrado do valor. Neste caso, vc terá uma nova lista criada alocando memória que pode facilmente explodir dependendo do número de elementos de sua lista fonte.
No caso das GENERATOR FUNCTIONS (definição de funções que utilizam yield e não return), elas retornam um GENERATOR OBJECT que no fundo no fundo é um iterator. Este iterator consegue salvar o estado atual do objeto acessando o próximo a partir do anterior, com isso vc não precisa em momento algum alocar sua lista inteira. Os valores são acessados sob demanda em um loop ou através da build-in function next(). Ao utilizar o yield sua função funciona como uma corrotina, na primeira vez que é chamada, a função começa executar desde sua primeira linha, ao chegar no yield ela para retornando o valor definido ao ser chamada novamente ela começa a rodar da linha seguinte ao yield com isso ela consegue funcionar como um iterador.
Outra forma de criar interator's em python é através da orientação a objetos utilizando os dunder methods **iter** e **next**.

Vou colocar a fonte de um livro muito bom sobre este tópico.

[Powerful Python: The Most Impactful Patterns, Features and Development Strategies Modern Python Provides](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074JG8W8Z)