# Dividir uma lista em n sublistas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

O que eu preciso é dividir esta lista em *n* sublistas, neste caso não dá para fazer manualmente pois o *n* vai ser dinâmico.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Pode fazer assim, caso de querer 3 sublistas:

```
n = 3
splited = [l[i::n] for i in range(n)]
print(splited) # [[0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [1, 4, 7, 10, 13], [2, 5, 8, 11, 14]]
```

Se quiser que os elementos das sublistas mantenham a sequencia:

```
n = 3
splited = []
len_l = len(l)
for i in range(n):
    start = int(i*len_l/n)
    end = int((i+1)*len_l/n)
    splited.append(l[start:end])
print(splited) # [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Note que neste caso o número de elementos é divisível por n (3), se tivessemos por exemplo `n = 4` o número de elementos em cada sublista ia ser diferente:

```
splited = [[0, 4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11]]
```

Ou, seguindo o segundo exemplo:

```
splited = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: Excelente resposta. Só  é legal evitar a letra `l` como nome de variável - mesmo de vida curta, por conta da legibilidade,

Comment: Obgado @jsbueno, só coloquei `l` porque é nome da lista também na pergunta

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
def chunks(lista, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lista), n):
        yield lista[i:i + n]

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
print(list(chunks(l, 3)))

# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
```

<kbd>[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/1608936)</kbd>

É feita uma *iteração* sobre a *lista*, ao especificar o terceiro argumento do [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#range), *step*, é indicado a que passo será feita a *iteração*, e ao usar o [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) os *pedaços* serão retornados mantendo o estado donde parou, até o término da *iteração*.

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/RUo5Dx)

**Nota**: A função acima irá gerar *sublistas* de *n* elementos, no exemplo, *3*.

Para dividir a lista em *n sublistas*, faça assim:

```
def chunks(lista, n):
    inicio = 0
    for i in range(n):
        final = inicio + len(lista[i::n])
        yield lista[inicio:final]
        inicio = final

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
print(list(chunks(l, 3)))

# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

<kbd>[**Fonte**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/425397/#c5)</kbd>

Para dividir a lista em *n sublistas* é informado o *início* e *final*, o *início* é donde você quer começar a dividir, *final* é a quantidade de elementos que cada *sublista* vai ter, o `yield` retorna a *sublista*, e em seguida é atribuído a variável `inicio` o valor de `final`, que representa a posição da *sublista* anterior, assim sucessivamente até o término da *iteração*.

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/gNDelo)

---

Nas perguntas abaixo tem algumas explicações sobre o `yield`:

1. [Qual a utilidade da palavra reservada `yield`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/6454)
2. [Para que serve o `yield`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/6454)

Answer (score 1):

A partir do [**Python 3.12**](https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html) (outubro de 2023) é possível usar a [função `itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched), que serve justamente para retornar pedaços de um iterável, um por vez:

```py
from itertools import batched

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
n = 3 # quantidade de sublistas
sublistas = [ list(pedaco) for pedaco in batched(l, len(l) // n) ]
print(sublistas) # [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Como a função recebe o tamanho de cada pedaço, precisei dividir o tamanho da lista pela quantidade de sub-listas. Outro detalhe é que `batched` retorna tuplas, então precisei convertê-las para listas.

Porém, um detalhe que não ficou claro é o que fazer quando a quantidade de elementos não é múltiplo da quantidade de sub-listas. No caso acima deu certo porque a lista tem 15 elementos, e como queremos 3 sub-listas, cada uma terá 5 elementos.

Mas se a lista tivesse 20 elementos e quiséssemos 6 sub-listas, como ficaria? Poderia ser 5 listas com 3 elementos e a última com 5, ou então 4 listas com 3 elementos e 2 listas com 4 elementos. Para casos assim, as outras soluções (como [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147477/112052)) já tratam isso. `batched` é mais adequado quando o tamanho de cada sub-lista não varia (exceto a última, que pode ficar com menos elementos - mas aqui a última pode ficar com mais, já que o mais importante é respeitar a quantidade de sub-listas).

Answer (score 0):

Aqui:

```
aLista = [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

aLista = iter(aLista)
result = []

for i in aLista:
    try:
        result.append([i, next(aLista)])
    except Exception:
        result.append([i])

print(result)
```