# Como dividir sem usar funções uma string em n partes iguais no python 3.8?

Tags: python, string, for

Estou querendo dividir uma string, no caso um número binário, para converter em octal e hex, mas preciso dividir o número inserido em partes iguais, no caso do octal, precisaria dividir de 3 em 3. como posso fazer isso em python 3.8?. Ps: sem usar funções prontas, acredito que por for ou while daria, mas não tenho certeza. Me ajudem por favor.

```
n = input("Binario:")
o = ""

for i in range(len(n)-2):
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "000"):
    o = o + "0"
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "001"):
    o = o + "1"
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "010"):
    o = o + "2"
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "011"):
    o = o + "3"
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "100"):
    o = o + "4"
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "101"):
    o = o + "5"
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "110"):
    o = o + "6"
  if(n[0+i]+n[1+i]+n[2+i] == "111"):
    o = o + "7"
print(o)
```

Fiz assim, mas ele pega valores sem ter que pegar.

Comment: Olá @MarcusLoureiro, não coloque imagem do código, cole o código entre três aspas simples invertidas (```código```)

Comment: [Isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147476/112052) talvez ajude (apesar de ser com listas, com strings também dá pra usar o que tem lá).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá

### Dividindo string

```
>>> bs = '0010010010001100'

>>> n = 3
>>> while (len(bs) % n) != 0:
...     bs = '0' + bs
...
```

A variável `n` possui o tamanho das partes em que a string precisa ser quebrada.

O `while` garante que a `string` possua o tamanho mínimo para que seja divisível por `n` (no caso três). O tamanho de `bs` é, neste exemplo, igual a `16`. Que não é divisível por `3`, sendo assim um `0` é adicionado ao início da `string`. Na segunda passagem o tamanho de `bs` é `17` e mais uma vez é adicionado um `0` na frente de `bs`. Por fim, o tamanho de `bs` é igual a `18` e o loop termina.

```
>>> bs
'000010010010001100'

>>> partes = [bs[index : index + n] for index in range(0, len(bs), n)]

>>> partes
['000', '010', '010', '010', '001', '100']
```

A variável `partes` recebe uma lista a partir de um `list comprehension` que seria o mesmo que abaixo:

```
partes = []
for index in range(0, len(bs), n):
    partes.append(bs[index : index + n])
```

O comando `for` itera sobre um `range` que varia de `0` até `18` (baseado no exemplo, saltando de `n` em `n`, ou seja, de `3` em `3`.

São incluidos na lista `partes` os *slicing* de `bs`. No primeiro momento do loop seria `bs[0:0+3]` - `000` - , no segundo seria `bs[3:3+3]` - `010` - e assim por diante.

### Usando o que o Python tem de bom

```
>>> bs = '0010010010001100'

>>> hexs = f'{int(bs, 2):X}'
>>> hexs
'248C'

>>> octs = f'{int(bs, 2):o}'
>>> octs
'22214'

>>> f'{int(bs, 2)}'
'9356'
```

Comment: Olá. não entendi o código, poderia me explicar? no caso a parte do while e das partes = ...