# percorrer lista python e dividi-la a cada interação

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho uma lista na qual eu preciso percorre-la e dividi-la de forma que a cada interação ela comece pelo próximo valor da lista.

vou colocar o que eu já tentei e o resultado, bem como o resultado que eu espero ter.

```
x = 3

lista = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

for i in lista:

  final_list= lambda test_list, x: [test_list[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(lista), x)]
  output=final_list(lista, x)
  print(output)
```

essa e a saida que obtive.

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

No entanto, preciso que meu resultado seja dessa forma.

```
[['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6'], ['7','8','9']]
[['2','3','4'], ['5','6','7'], ['8','9']]
[['3','4','5'], ['6','7','8'], ['9']]
[['4','5','6'], ['7','8','9']]
[['5','6','7'], ['8','9']]
[['6','7','8'], ['9']]
[['7','8','9']]
```

Peço que me ajudem pois sou novo no python e estou a dois dias tentando resolver este problema. Não precisa deixar o código pronto, preciso somente de um norte pra eu destravar aqui.

Comment: Conforme indicado no link sugerido acima no box azul, não precisa criar um lambda a cada iteração, é completamente desnecessário. Creio que basta adaptar [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147478/112052), fazendo com que a variável `inicio` seja dinâmica (indo de zero até o tamanho do array menos 3, no seu caso)

Answer (score 2):

Estou engatinhando no Python. Ainda nem tinha visto lambda, mas já conhecia list comprehension. Olhei a sua dúvida e tentei resolver. Era isso que você queria?

```
x = 3

lista = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

for i in lista[2:9] :
    final_list= lambda test_list, x : [test_list[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(lista), x)]
    output=final_list(lista, x)
    print(output)
    lista.pop(0)
```

Comment: Adicione na resposta o link dum sandbox online que ajuda as pessoas testarem a sua solução: https://ideone.com/TxrucJ explicações do que e o porque foi modificado também atraem votos positivos.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelas dicas!