# Python / Django intervalo de horas

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Preciso criar uma grade de horas para uma agenda:

Tenho as seguintes informações no template do Django:

Hora inicial: 08:00

Hora final: 18:00

Intervalo em minutos 00:30

Eu teria como implementar algo como:

```
for hora in range(hrInicial, hrFinal, intervalo):
      print(hora)

08:00
08:30
09:00
09:30
...
```

Essa seria a parametrização para criação da agenda, por este motivo não tenho a data, somente a hora.  A ideia é cadastrar para cada dia da semana um período especifico.
Ex.:

```
Segunda - 08:00 as 12:00
Terça   - 08:00 as 18:00
Quarta  - 12:00 as 18:00
...
```

No template considerando o intervalo de 30 minutos para segunda, quero exibir:

```
08:00
08:30
09:00
09:30
10:00
10:30
11:00
11:30
12:00
```

Pesquisei nas perguntas similares, mas para Python, não encontrei pergunta similar.

Obrigado pela força.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o módulo `datetime`, com os tipos `datetime`, `timedelta` e `time`. O único detalhe é que você necessariamente precisará informar uma data, isto é, ano, mês e dia, porém, como nos interessa apenas o horário, qualquer data válida será possível, pois, no final, ela será desconsiderada. Neste exemplo, eu utilizei a data 01/01/2017.

A lógica é a seguinte: você pode criar um objeto do tipo `datetime` da seguinte forma

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
>>> hrInicial = datetime(2017, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0)
```

Perceba que tive que informar a data inicialmente e, após, informei a hora, 8, minutos, 0, e segundos, 0. Posso verificar se o horário foi definido corretamente fazendo:

```
>>> print(hrInicial.time())
08:00:00
```

Para adicionar um intervalo de tempo, utilizamos o tipo `timedelta`. Para um intervalo de 30 minutos, fazemos:

```
>>> intervalo = timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Podemos adicionar este intervalo ao horário inicial com o operador de soma mesmo:

```
>>> novaHora = hrInicial + intervalo
>>> print(novaHora.time())
08:30:00
```

Perceba que o horário foi incrementado como esperado. Utilizando esta lógica, podemos criar uma função genérica:

```
def get_interval (inicio, fim, intervalo):

    """ 
    Retorna a lista de horários entre `inicio` e `fim`, inclusive, com um intervalo definido por `intervalo`.

    @param inicio    iterable Lista de três valores no formato (hora, minutos, segundos)
    @param fim       iterable Lista de três valores no formato (hora, minutos, segundos)
    @param intervalo iterable Lista de três valores no formato (hora, minutos, segundos)
    @return generator
    """

    inicio = datetime(2017, 1, 1, *inicio)
    fim = datetime(2017, 1, 1, *fim)

    iHoras, iMinutos, iSegundos = intervalo

    intervalo = timedelta(hours=iHoras, minutes=iMinutos, seconds=iSegundos)

    while inicio <= fim:
        yield inicio.time()
        inicio += intervalo
```

Os parâmetros serão uma lista de três valores: o primeiro define as horas, o segundo os minutos e o terceiro os segundos. Desta forma, podemos fazer:

```
>>> hrInicial = (8, 0, 0)
>>> hrFinal   = (12, 0, 0)
>>> intervalo = (0, 30, 0)
>>> for hora in get_interval(hrInicial, hrFinal, intervalo):
...     print(hora)
08:00:00
08:30:00
09:00:00
09:30:00
10:00:00
10:30:00
11:00:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/CSAGxZ).

Comment: Excelente solução.  Não conhecia o "yield", muito bom.  Obrigado por mais essa grande ajuda.

Comment: Mais informações sobre `yield`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92921/para-que-serve-o-yield