# Obter lista de CSV com Python

Tags: python, lista, csv

Tenho um arquivo CSV com mais de 9000 linhas. Estou precisando obter uma lista somente com um dado de cada linha.

Um exemplo é o seguinte:

```
01/02/19,carlos,casa,rio
03/05/18,luis,carro,maceio
06/04/17,camila,celular,teresina
```

Preciso obter uma lista somente com os nomes:

```
lista = ['carlos','luis','camila']
```

o mais perto que cheguei com esse código:

```
csvRows=[]
arq_contas = open ('C:.../lista_contas.csv')
leitura_contas = csv.reader(arq_contas,delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
for row in leitura_contas:
    csvRows.append(row[1:2])
    print(csvRows)
```

mas obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
['carlos'], [], ['luis'], [], ['camila'], [],
```

sou iniciante em Python e em programação com um todo. Por isso estou precisando de uma luz de vocês.

Comment: Tenta substituir `row[1:2]` por `row[1]`

Comment: o resultado foi somente: ['carlos']

Comment: Somente o primeiro é `['carlos']`, mas no final do laço será `['carlos', 'luis', 'camila']`. [Veja aqui](https://repl.it/@acwoss/EquatorialBisqueEngineer).

Comment: quando eu executo o meu aparece somente  ['carlos'] e depois esse erro: csvRows.append(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Então é provável que você esteja executando um código diferente do da pergunta.

Comment: encontrei o que está dando erro. Em cada linha tem um \n. (https://repl.it/repls/DarksalmonAliceblueNanocad)

Answer (score 1):

Como [você mostrou](https://repl.it/repls/DarksalmonAliceblueNanocad), o problema é que seu arquivo CSV não está formatado corretamente, visto que há uma linha em branco entre os registros. Não que isso invalide, de fato, o formato, mas basicamente cada linha em branco seria um registro nulo, o que não faria  muito sentido.

Do seu código, a única correção necessária para gerar o resultado desejado é alterar `row[1:2]` por `row[1]`, pois da primeira forma você estaria pegando duas colunas e não apenas uma.

Uma solução um pouco mais elaborada seria:

```
import csv

def get_csv_column(filename, column):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream)
        for row in reader:
            yield row[column]

print( list(get_csv_column('dados.csv', 1)) )
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AccomplishedMiniatureDiscussions)</sup>

- [Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)
- [Para que serve o Yield?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Anderson, agradeço muito a atenção, mas com o seu código o erro continua:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

realmente é um erro causado pela formatação do CSV, mas não estou conseguindo corrigir isso.

Hoje testei o código:

```
entrada = open('C:/...arquivo.csv','r')
saida = open('C:/...saida_arquivo.csv','w')
for linha in entrada:
    l = str(linha.split(','))
    saida.write(l)
entrada.close()
saida.close()
```

com esse código obtive o seguinte:

```
['02/22/18', 'rosalvaponteatelierdecriacao', 'General', 'liked\n']['\n']['02/22/18', 'idealaeventobar', 'General', 'liked\n']['\n']['02/22/18', 'jasmim_wedding_trend', 'General', 'liked\n']['\n']
```