# Dois "return" em uma função

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, return

Como que funciona caso exista dois (+) `return` em uma função do Python? Teria como retornar o segundo valor, ou só o primeiro?

Exemplo:

```
def soma(a, b):
    x = a + b
    y = 'qualquer coisa'
    return x
    return y
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eu havia perguntado em comentário porque no começo estava abstrato demais, ainda continua um pouco abstrato do que quer de fato, mas vamos lá as opções.

Isso não é possível. O `return` tem duas funções:

- estabelecer uma valor obtido por uma expressão contida nele, no caso usou apenas uma variável que será usado como **resultado** da função em algum outro lugar onde esta função foi chamada;
- mudar o fluxo de execução do código terminando imediatamente a execução da função que está sendo executado e **devolvendo o controle** para o local onde ela foi chamada.

Portanto após ele ser executado tudo o que vem a seguir no código não será executado. Neste caso o `return y` nunca será executado.

Só é possível ter mais que um `return` no código se houver uma guarda condicional onde um ou outro será executado sob certas circunstâncias. Há linguagens que tem até outras formas, mas não Python.

```
def soma(a, b):
    x = a + b
    y = 'qualquer coisa'
    if x > 5:
        return x
    else:
        return y
```

Mas se você quiser que realmente a execução tenha uma forma de continuar pode usar o [`yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/101). Ele é igual a um `return`, mas ele guarda o estado que estava e possivelmente continuará de onde parou. Talvez seja isso que esteja procurando, mas não parece. O `yield` não deixa de ser um `return`.

```
def soma(a, b):
    x = a + b
    y = 'qualquer coisa'
    yield x
    yield y
```

Mas aí não pode chamar a função de qualquer maneira, precisaria de um gerador para controlar o estado da função.

A não ser que deseja retornar duas coisas, e Python teve a felicidade de adotar o retorno múltiplo como uma tupla. mas não me parece que seja isto que deseja.

```
def soma(a, b):
    x = a + b
    y = 'qualquer coisa'
    return (x, y)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/ReturnTwo.py).

Depende de qual é sua necessidade pode adotar cada uma dessas estratégias para ter mais de um `return`, ou pelo menos mais de um valor retornado.

Answer (score 9):

O seu exemplo não tem objetivo algum, então não tem como dar muitos detalhes.

Se você precisa retornar mais de um valor da função, você pode retornar uma sequência, tal como uma lista, tupla, conjunto, etc.

```
def função():
    ...
    return (x, y)

x, y = função()
```

Porém, outra forma é retornar da função um gerador. O gerador também será um objeto iterável e você poderá "retornar" mais valores através dele, bastando percorrer os itens que ele gerar:

```
def função():
    ...
    yield x
    yield y

gen = função()

x = next(gen)
y = next(gen)
```

- [Para que serve o Yield?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/5878)

Answer (score 7):

O `return` termina imediatamente a execução da função retornando o valor em questão e o fluxo ao chamador. mesmo uma função que não defina explicitamente o `return` irá retornar `None`.

```
def grok():
    # faz alguma coisa

>>> valor = grok()
>>> valor is None
True
```

Por terminar imediatamente a execução da função outras declarações abaixo do mesmo nunca serão executadas a não ser que haja algum teste condicional verificando qual deva ser retornado.

```
def recebe_numero(numero):
    if (numero % 2 == 0):
        return "Par"
    else:
        return "Ímpar"
```

No exemplo acima existem duas declarações de `return` mas somente uma será executada dependendo do teste condicional.

Fui lembrado pelo @AndersonCarlosWoss que existem situações onde o Python mesmo após a execução de um `return` irá, digamos assim efetuar outras operações antes de permitir a retorno ao chamador como no caso da declaração `with` que executa o método mágico(dunder) `__exit__` antes de retornar ao fluxo.

Answer (score 6):

Se eu fosse você retornaria uma lista com os dois valores, por exemplo:

```
def soma(a, b):
    x = a + b
    y = 'qualquer coisa'
    return [x, y]
```

Ou senão, o Python te permite fazer um return com uma tupla de dois valores.

```
def soma(a, b):
    x = a + b
    y = 'qualquer coisa'
    return x, y
```

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia Anderson, muito obrigado.

Comment: É o que chamamos de *tuple packing*, caso queira pesquisar mais. Veja um exemplo: https://repl.it/@acwoss/AdventurousIntrepidDisks