# Qual a diferença entre FOR e DOSEQ em clojure

Tags: loop, for, programação-funcional, clojure

Qual diferença entre `for` e `doseq`?

Escrevi um programa, que me retorne o maior valor dentro dos parametros informados. Obs: sei que existe a função `max` e `max-key`, mas nao quero utiliza-las pois quero treinar a linguagem.

Exemplo:

Utilizando `doseq`, funciona.

```
(defn valorMaximo [& num]
  (let [x (atom (first num))]
    (doseq [i num] (when (> i @x) (reset! x i)) ) @x))
```

Utilizando `for`, não funciona.

```
(defn valorMaximo2 [& num]
  (let [x (atom (first num))]
    (for [i num :when (> i @x)] (reset! x i)) @x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o corpo do `for` não é avaliado até que seja necessário. É como uma [expressão geradora do Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/112052).

Como o `for` não executa seu corpo até que seja forçado, e você não está forçando a sua execução, os efeitos colaterais não acontecem.

De qualquer maneira, você não deveria estar usando `atom`. Este é um caso para `reduce`:

```
(defn valor-maximo [& num]
  (when-not (empty? num)
    (reduce (fn [max-atual n]
              (if (> n max-atual)
                n
                max-atual))
            num)))
```

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado, eu tinha visto a função `reduce` mas nao havia entendido seu funcionamento. mas agora ficou muito claro, obrigado