# Como fazer a média de valores em uma lista usando python?

Tags: python

Olá, eu possuo uma lista de valores em python que alternam entre valores positivos e negativos, e quero trabalhar com a média desses valores, porém, eu preciso que quando o número fiquei positivo se inicie a contagem dos valores e no ultimo número negativo antes de ficar positivo novamente, esse contador para e tira a média desses valores e ai se inicia uma nova contagem. Segue um exemplo do tipo dos dados:

```
   0;  2.3360; 0.4675
   1;  1.7439; 0.4174
   2;  1.3766; 0.3673
   3;  1.3766; 0.1719
   4;  1.4002; 0.1719
   5;  1.5687; 0.1719
   6;  2.2238; -0.6552
   7;  1.6181; -0.6552
   8;  2.2797; -0.6552
   9;  2.9562; -0.6552
  10;  3.4301; -0.6552
  11;  3.7597; -0.6552
  12;  4.0999; -0.6552
  13;  4.6294; -0.6552
  14;  4.4860; -0.6552
  15;  4.4504; 0.0356
  16;  4.3090; 0.1414
  17;  3.9967; 0.1556
  18;  3.8269; 0.1698
  19;  3.4952; 0.1978
  20;  3.2694; 0.1307
  21;  3.2059; 0.0635
  22;  3.1428; 0.0631
  23;  3.0802; 0.0626
  24;  2.9562; -0.0619
  25;  2.8950; -0.0612
  25;  2.8950; -0.0612
  26;  2.4214; -0.1155
  27;  2.2517; -0.1697
  28;  2.0055; -0.1900
  29;  1.7952; -0.1835
  30;  1.7952; 0.1835
```

Para esse caso por exemplo, eu precisaria tirar a média do 0 até o 14, do 15 até o 29, e a partir do 30 se iniciaria uma nova contagem.

Entretanto essa média é a media dos valores na segunda coluna, `vazmed[1]`, porém o range dessa média varia de acordo com a terceira coluna `vazmed[2]`.

Eu estou tentando fazer isso com uma variável auxiliar, porém sem sucesso.

Segue o código que eu construí até agora:

```
arquivo = open('vazdif.out', 'rt')

vazmed1 = []
vazmed2 = []

i = 0

for linha in arquivo:
    campo = linha.split(';')
    vaz1 = float(campo[1])
    vaz2 = float(campo[2])
    vazmed1.append(vaz1)
    vazmed2.append(vaz2)
    i = i+1
n = len(vazmed1)
m = sum(vazmed1)
aux = 0
for atual in vazmed2:
    if atual < 0:
        aux = 1
    if atual >= 0 and aux == 1:
        aux = 0
    if aux == 1:
        media = m/n
        print(media)
```

Alguma ajuda? Se possível eu gostaria de tentar resolver esse problema sem packeage como numpy e pandas

Comment: Tu adicionas todos os valores em `vasmed1` antes de calcular a media, assim tu apenas vai conseguir calcular a media da lista inteira. Calcule a media dentro do `for` cada vez que tu encontrares uma troca de valor positivo/negativo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu te recomendaria a começar a pensar em organizar suas soluções com funções, aplicando [o princípio da responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/5878). Quando você começa criar um código que faz tudo cedo ou tarde você perde o controle e ele passa a ficar mais complexo do que deveria ou difícil de manter.

Primeiro, podemos pensar numa função que lê o arquivo CSV e nos retorne uma lista com os valores para cada linha:

```py
import csv

def read_csv(filename, delimiter=';'):
  with open(filename) as stream:
    reader = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=delimiter)
    yield from reader
```

Aqui vale notar que o `yield` é responsável por definir um gerador. [Para que serve o Yield?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/5878) Neste ponto, se você consumir seu gerador, teria algo como:

```py
for row in read_csv('data.csv'):
  print(row)

['0', '  2.3360', ' 0.4675']
['1', '  1.7439', ' 0.4174']
['2', '  1.3766', ' 0.3673']
['3', '  1.3766', ' 0.1719']
...
['28', '  2.0055', ' -0.1900']
['29', '  1.7952', ' -0.1835']
['30', '  1.7952', ' 0.1835']
```

Perceba que os espaços em branco que estão sobrando no arquivo permanecem na nossa saída.

A segunda função que podemos imaginar é tratar esses dados, de forma que possamos utilizar o valor como float de fato, e já gerar a separação dos conjuntos de valores, que aqui chamarei de *chunks* (e não é a toa). A ideia é consumir o gerador até que certa condição seja satisfeita para finalizar o *chunk*. Essa condição é que o valor atual seja positivo e o anterior negativo ou o final dos dados. Assim, podemos fazer:

```py
def create_chunks(data):
  values = []
  previous_is_negative = False

  for row in data:
    value = float(row[2].strip())
    if value >= 0 and previous_is_negative:
      yield values
      values = []
      previous_is_negative = False
    elif value < 0:
      previous_is_negative = True
    values.append(value)
  yield values
```

> **Nota:** em `row[2].strip()` a chamada de `strip` é desnecessária neste contexto pois a própria função `float` já irá desconsiderar espaços em branco no início e final da *string*.

A função irá consumir o gerador de entrada, `data`, e irá acumular os valores em `values` até que a condição, `if value >= 0 and previous_is_negative`, seja satisfeita. Quando ocorrer, é *retornado* os valores acumulados e reiniciado as variáveis. Se os dados se encerrarem antes da condição ser satisfeita todos os valores são *retornados* e a função é encerrada.

Assim, já poderíamos fazer:

```py
data = read_csv('data.csv')
for chunk in create_chunks(data):
  print(chunk)

[0.4675, 0.4174, 0.3673, 0.1719, 0.1719, 0.1719, -0.6552, -0.6552, -0.6552, -0.6552, -0.6552, -0.6552, -0.6552, -0.6552, -0.6552]
[0.0356, 0.1414, 0.1556, 0.1698, 0.1978, 0.1307, 0.0635, 0.0631, 0.0626, -0.0619, -0.0612, -0.0612, -0.1155, -0.1697, -0.19, -0.1835]
[0.1835]
```

Perceba que foram gerados os três *chunks* desejados. A partir disso basta calcular a média dos valores de cada *chunk*:

```py
import statistics

# ...

for chunk in create_chunks(data):
  print(statistics.mean(chunk))

-0.27526
0.011068750000000002
0.1835
```