# Obter somente os trechos entre colchetes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Em um software de terceiros, um registro de log é gerado com informações separadas através de palavras que vem dentro de um colchetes.

Exemplo: `[informação1] [informação2] [informação3]`

O problema é que a biblioteca `re` do Python não aceita que eu faça o `split` dessas informações separando com base nos colchetes, exemplo:

Caso eu queria pegar tudo que tem dentro dos colchetes, ele irá me apresentar um erro porque não pode fazer os cortes e separação usando caracteres especiais como colchetes, asteriscos, e operadores matemáticos.

Nesse caso não há como mudar no software para as informações não serem entregues através dos parênteses.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como contornar este problema?

```
 import re
    
    padrao = ''
    texto = r"[1232131] testando [teste2] [teste3] e [teste4]"
    
    #divide o texto numa lista de acordo com o padrão
    saida = re.split(padrao, texto)
    i = 1
    for pedaco in saida:
        print("Split {0}: {1}".format(i, pedaco))
        i+=1
```

Comment: Sua informação está equivocada, você pode capturar colchetes e caracteres especiais com regex. Para isso use o [caractere `\\`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html) para fazer o escape de caracteres especiais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *não pode fazer os cortes e separação usando caracteres especiais como colchetes, asteriscos, e operadores matemáticos*

É claro que pode. Mas em vez de fazer um `split`, acho mais fácil pegar somente os trechos que você quer (no caso, tudo que está entre colchetes):

```
import re
    
texto = r"[1232131] testando [teste2] [teste3] e [teste4]"

for i, pedaco in enumerate(re.findall(r'\[([^]]+)\]', texto), start=1):
    print(f"Split {i}: {pedaco}")
```

A expressão usada foi `\[([^]]+)\]`. Explicando por partes:

- Ela começa com `\[` e termina com `\]`, ou seja, ela pega todo trecho que começa com um `[` e termina com um `]`. Só que colchetes [têm significado especial em regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), por isso eu preciso fazer o escape com `\` para que eles sejam considerados caracteres comuns
- Entre os colchetes temos `[^]]`, que é uma [classe de caracteres negada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), que pega qualquer caractere que não seja `]`. Depois temos o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que indica "uma ou mais ocorrências"

Ou seja, a regex pega um `[`, seguido de um ou mais caracteres que não são `]`, seguido de um `]`. Além disso, o trecho que corresponde aos caracteres que não são `]` está entre parênteses, o que forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E quando há grupos de captura na regex, [`findall` retorna somente os grupos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Também uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para já termos os índices juntamente com os valores retornados por `findall`, assim você não precisa ficar incrementando `i` (e usei [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) para formatar a saída, disponível a partir do Python 3.6 - mas também pode continuar usando `format` se quiser). A saída será:

```
Split 1: 1232131
Split 2: teste2
Split 3: teste3
Split 4: teste4
```

---

Também dá para fazer com `split`, mas aí você teria que separar não só por colchetes, mas também por todo o texto entre cada par de colchetes, o que na minha opinião ficaria bem mais complicado, então achei mais simples você definir o que quer pegar em vez de dizer como quer separar.

Afinal, [*split* e *match* são dois lados da mesma moeda](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch): no primeiro você diz o que não quer (texto que não está entre colchetes) e separa os dados segundo este critério, no segundo você diz o que quer (texto entre colchetes) e obtém somente isso. E há situações em que definir um é mais fácil do que o outro - neste caso, `split` me parece ser mais difícil, veja:

```
r = re.compile(r'\][^\[]+\[|[\[\]]')
for i, pedaco in enumerate(filter(lambda s : len(s) > 0, r.split(texto)), start=1):
    print(f"Split {i}: {pedaco}")
```

A ideia é fazer o `split` por um `]` seguido de vários caracteres que não são `[`, seguido de um `[`, ou por um colchetes (seja de abertura ou fechamento) sozinho. Só que isso faz com que o resultado tenha strings vazias (quando o separador está no início ou fim da string - [conforme explicado na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)), então preciso filtrar esses valores do resultado usando [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

---

Se quiser ser mais específico, pode trocar para algo como `re.findall(r'\[([\w]+)\]', texto)` - no caso, `\w` é um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para "letras, dígitos ou o caractere `_`".

Isso é um pouco mais restrito, já que `[^]]` pega qualquer caractere que não seja `]` (qualquer um mesmo, incluindo sinais de pontuação, espaços, emojis, quebras de linha, etc). Se quiser ser mais restrito, basta ajustar a regex de acordo (não tem jeito, uma regex mais simples pode acabar pegando coisas a mais, mas uma mais restritiva pode acabar ficando mais complicada - cabe a você escolher o que faz mais sentido de acordo com os dados que você tem).

---

#### Sem regex

Outra alternativa é não usar regex, e em vez disso, usar o [método `find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) para procurar pelos colchetes, e em seguida obter a substring entre as posições destes:

```
def texto_entre_colchetes(texto):
    inicio = 0
    while True:
        inicio = texto.find('[', inicio)
        if inicio == -1:
            break
        fim = texto.find(']', inicio + 1)
        if fim == -1:
            break
        yield texto[inicio + 1: fim]
        inicio = fim + 1

texto = r"[1232131] testando [teste2] [teste3] e [teste4]"

for i, pedaco in enumerate(texto_entre_colchetes(texto), start=1):
    print(f"Split {i}: {pedaco}")
```

Eu uso o segundo parâmetro de `find`, que é a posição na qual a busca começa, assim eu posso buscar a partir do último colchete encontrado. Quando não tiver mais, `find` retorna `-1` e eu posso encerrar o *loop*.

Sobre o uso do `yield` acima, [leia aqui para entender melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/112052).

Comment: Eu falei parenteses ali em cima, mas era colchetes rsrs. Perfeito cara, resolveu meu problema. Muito Obrigado @hkotsubo.