# Como fatiar uma string separando conjunto de letras e conjunto de números em python?

Tags: python, string, lista, split

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a string `"A32B32C50A1V14G1B1"` e gostaria de separá-la em listas diferentes, mas não sei como faço uma solução funcional, pois não há parâmetro para a quantidade de casas dos números e, ao verificá-los um por um, o armazenamento do número na lista fica fragmentado.

Portanto não consigo atribuir o número 32 a letra A, pois a letra A está na posição 0 da lista de letras e na posição 0 da lista de números está somente o 3. A resolução do problema é multiplicar cada letra pelo número de vezes do número que aparece após ela.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAVVVVVVVVVVVVVVGB
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa criar outras listas. Basta fazer um *loop* pelos caracteres da string e ir analisando um a um:

- se for uma letra, guarde-a até que o número posterior seja lido
- se for um dígito, continue lendo até não ter mais dígitos, atualizando o valor do número
- quando encontrar outra letra, ou a string terminar, retorne a letra repetida várias vezes (a quantidade é o número)

Ficaria assim:

```py
def get_parts(s):
    numero = 0
    for char in s: # para cada caractere da string
        if char.isalpha(): # é uma letra
            if numero > 0: # se acabou o número e começou outra letra
                yield letra * numero # retorna a letra repetida várias vezes
                numero = 0
            letra = char
        elif char.isdigit(): # se é um número
            # atualiza o valor do número atual
            numero = 10 * numero + int(char)
    # retorna também o último
    yield letra * numero

s = 'A32B32C50A1V14G1B1'
print(''.join(get_parts(s)))
# AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCAVVVVVVVVVVVVVVGB
```

Eu uso `yield` para criar uma função geradora (mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/112052)), que vai percorrendo a string e retornando uma letra repetida várias vezes, conforme vai lendo seus caracteres. Depois uso `join` para juntar essas partes.

Basicamente, eu leio a letra e depois o número. Como eu leio o número dígito a dígito, vou atualizando o seu valor. Por exemplo, primeiro eu leio o `3`, depois quando eu leio o `2`, basta multiplicar o 3 por 10 e somar com 2, resultando em 32.

Quando eu terminei de ler o número (seja porque encontrei outra letra, ou porque a string terminou), basta "multiplicar" a letra pelo número. Em Python, quando você multiplica uma string por um número, o resultado é a string repetida várias vezes.

---

Se quiser também pode concatenar diretamente na string final (usando a ideia geral do código acima):

```py
s = 'A32B32C50A1V14G1B1'
numero = 0
result = ''
for char in s: # para cada caractere da string
    if char.isalpha(): # é uma letra
        if numero > 0: # se acabou o número e começou outra letra
            result += letra * numero # adiciona a letra repetida várias vezes
            numero = 0
        letra = char
    elif char.isdigit(): # se é um número
        # atualiza o valor do número atual
        numero = 10 * numero + int(char)
# adiciona também o último
result += letra * numero
print(result)
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar regex:

```py
import re

resultado = ''.join(match[1] * int(match[2]) for match in re.finditer(r'([A-Z])(\d+)', s))
print(resultado)
```

`[A-Z]` pega uma letra de "A" a "Z", e `\d+` pega um ou mais dígitos. Cada uma dessas partes está entre parênteses, o que forma [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Assim, eu consigo pegar esses grupos depois: `match[1]` retorna o primeiro grupo (a letra) e `match[2]` retorna o segundo grupo (os dígitos). Por fim uso uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) para iterar por todos os resultados de `finditer`, e uso `join` para juntar tudo.

Se quiser considerar também letras minúsculas, pode trocar para `re.finditer(r'([A-Z])(\d+)', s, re.I)` - a [*flag* `I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) torna a regex *case insensitive*.

Comment: Verdade, a resposta anterior era um pouco mais difícil de implementar. Ontem, depois de várias horas, consegui fazê-la funcionar, mas tive muito problema com o escopo das variáveis quando ia compará-las, pois a todo momento tinha que mudar o tipo para conseguir fazer a comparação de forma correta! Sua solução foi bem prática e simples de entender. Foi exatamente como tentei fazer de início, usando uma multiplicação por 10 para não perder o número. Gostei bastante do uso da função 'yield' ela se aplica muito bem a esse tipo de situação, tentarei continuar utilizando. Obrigado pelo ensinamento!